# Proper JSON formatting in Ajax

Tags: javascript, ruby, json

I have a simple Friendship model to allow users to connect with one another:

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :sender, class_name: "User"
 belongs_to :receiver, class_name: "User"
end
```

In the User model I have this method defined:

```
 def self.create_friendship(receiver)
  Friendship.create(sender_id: current_user.id, receiver_id: receiver)
 end
```

My User Index view has this simple Javascript:

```
<script>
 $("#searchbutton").click(function(){
  var tod = $("#timeofday").val()
  console.log(tod);
  var dow = $("#dayofweek").val()
  console.log(dow);

  queries = {'time': tod , 'day': dow }
  $("#myselect").html("");
  $.ajax({
    url:'/users.json',
    type:'GET',
    data: {search: queries},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function( json ) {
    //console.debug(json)
    $.each(json.users, function(index, value) {
      $('#myselect').append($('<option>').text(value.name).attr('value', value.id));
    });
  }
});

})

$('#addbutton').click(function(){
  var x = $("#myselect").val()

  receiver = {}
})


</script>
```

What's confusing me is the best way to format the JSON data to be plugged into the User create method.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do it is to use form tags with remote: true. They automatically format data properly. More than that, by default Rails checks csrf_token in non-GET queries and form tags automatically include that token.

To handle form reactions to different events you can use UJS: [list of events fired on form](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax).